# Sort Array of AWS3 objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have a collection of aws objects. I would like to sort the objects according to last modified time. See the below snippet

```
array = [<AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013.csv>,
         <AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013_October.csv>, 
         <AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013_September_176.csv>, 
         <AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013_September_1764.csv>
        ]
```

I need to sort the array with respect to last modified time of that particular file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
array = [<AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013.csv>,
         <AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013_October.csv>, 
         <AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013_September_176.csv>, 
         <AWS::S3::S3Object:dt_publisher_reports/temp/2013_September_1764.csv>]

array.sort_by &:last_modified
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 array.sort_by &:updated_at
```

or

```
 array.order(:updated_at)
```

Comment: If array.sort_by &:last_modified is working then the others are also in the same manner right :)